# jQuery Multiple On()

Tags: jquery

I am having some difficultly switching out my live() scripts to on(). I have multiple on() in the same js file that fire. For some reason, when I switched to on(), the the first click fired but the second did not. Here is my code.

When this is fired, a window opens.

```
$("#Add_Member").on("click",function() {
    // Do Something
});
```

Which allows me to use this. But when I click...

```
$("#Close_Add_Member").on("click",function() {
});
```

Nothing happens. Any suggestions?

**UPDATED - This is the first click that is fired in detail**

```
$("#Add_Member").on("click",function() {
        // Get Member ID    
        var Member_id = $(".Window").attr("id");    
        var dataString = "MemberId="+Member_id+"";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/file.php",
        timeout: 3000,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(myhtml){
            // Success
        }
    });

}); // End Add Member
```

Comment: Not a whole lot to go on here. Is #Close_Add_Member an actual ID?

Comment: I'd suggest checking that event was attached right first, by adding some debugging code into the called function - `alert()` or `console.log()`, for example. If this code will be executed, the problem is with function itself, not with `on()`

Comment: Your update isn't really relevant to the issue; if anything, we'd need to see the value of "myhtml" and your success function definition.  I'm sure our answers will still apply, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the element with Close_Add_Member is not defined until after the Add_Member click opens and renders a new part of the DOM?  That being the case, you can't use the `.bind()` style of binding with `.on()`, but instead have to use the `.delegate()` style, like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "#Close_Add_Member", function () {

});
```

Of course, it would be better to use a closer parent to #Close_Add_Member than just `document`, but whatever you choose has to contain #Close_Add_Member and exist when you make the call to `.on()`.

Comment: Changing it to $(document).on("click","#Close_Add_Member",function() { works perfect. Thanks